# Why am I getting a syntax error "Syntax error at input '('"?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the following code, I keep getting this Syntax error  `Syntax error at input '('`

```
if longEntry
if  strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long, strategy.equity/close)
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Once you start listing parameter names in the function call like (`id=`, `direction=` etc.), you should keep using them for the next parameters too.

So, you should add `qty=` before `strategy.equity/close`.

```
if  strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long, qty = strategy.equity/close)
```